# Connection failure - AWS RDS and mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have setup numerous databases on AWS RDS SQL, however mySQL workbench fails to connect to the databases. I have read online that my machine IP address must be added to the security group of the database. However that option is not available.

If anyone can provide an insight into whether the security group can only be accessed with the premium plan with AWS RDS as i'm currently using the free tier

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.Authorizing

Comment: Thank you - I have come across this guide. However, the security group option is not visible in the left pane

Answer (score 12):

> Yes, you can access AWS RDS in workbench free tier also.

you need to fix some issue before connecting via workbench.

For access AWS RDS to the remote machine, you need to give **Public Accessibility 'Yes'** when you create AWS RDS instance.

[image]

Also, you need to add your public IP address in AWS RDS security group with port 3306 in inbound rule.

[image]

For more details click here: https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/09/connect-aws-rds-mysql-instance-with-phpmyadmin.html

Comment: Updating inbound rule is of utmost importance, also for those who may see error 1045 in SQLYog "access denied" or something similar in workbench etc do not copy paste credentials form RDS console, just type them in yourself, wasted 2 hours due to this when I knew I was copy/pasting correctly!! may save some time!